# Как правильно образовывать форму родительного падежа множественного числа?

Tags: словообразование, падежи

Как правильно пишется?

1. Без апельсин или апельсинов
2. Без погон или без погонов

Answer (score 3):

Названия плодов, фруктов и овощей, представляющие собой существительные мужского рода, в начальной форме оканчивающиеся на твердый согласный (мандарин, баклажан, апельсин, помидор), в форме родительного падежа множественного числа имеют окончание -ов: пять мандаринов, килограмм баклажанов, Новый год **без апельсинов**, салат из помидоров.

В словаре "ГОВОРИМ ПРАВИЛЬНО" — без п***о***гон.
Парные существительные в родительном падеже множественного числа не имеют окончаний: ботинок (не ботинков), сапог (не сапогов), погон (не погонов).

Answer (score 1):

а *носки-носков* - исключение?

Answer (score 0):

Апельсины - не парные предметы, поэтому склоняются "апельсинов". А вот погоны - парные, таким образом, будет "погон" (точно также, как *туфель, чулок, ног* и т.д.)